# Facebook OAuth Error validating verification code sometimes happen

Tags: facebook, api, oauth, oauth-2.0

I have a very strange problem with authenticating facebook users. Basically it works for 90% of users, but for 10% I alwayas get an error " Error validating verification code". They tried to login from different browsers, OS and they always get the same error.

I did all by the book:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?scope=email%2C+user_birthday%2C+publish_stream%2C+publish_actions%2C+user_hometown&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fapps.facebook.com%2Fbetchallenge%2F&client_id=.....
```

Then I grab a code parameter from the response and send new reqest:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_secret=...&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fapps.facebook.com%2Fbetchallenge%2F&code=...&client_id=212564568790055
```

I followed all the rules, redirect_uris are the same, they don't have any special characters like ?....

Any ideas?

Comment: I solved the problem. The problem was with users who set in their facebook account to connect to facebook via HTTPS. In that case you have to send https requests to facebook , not http (although in my example it is https, acutally I wasn't using https).

Comment: It would be better to post that as an answer instead, so it would be clear to people coming in from Google that your problem has been solved.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. The problem was with users who set in their facebook account to connect to facebook via HTTPS. In that case you have to send https requests to facebook , not http (although in my example it is https, acutally I wasn't using https)