# facebook Access Token 400 bad request

Tags: facebook, authentication, facebook-oauth

I am using following code to retrieve facebook accessToken

```
string url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?" +
                         "client_id={0}" +
                         "&redirect_uri={1}" +
                         "&client_secret={2}" +
                         "&code={3}";
            url = string.Format(url, clientId, redirectUri.EncodeUrl(), clientSecret, code);
            //Create a webrequest to perform the request against the Uri
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
            try
            {
                //read out the response as a utf-8 encoding and parse out the access_token
                using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
                {
                    using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        //string urlRedirects = response.ResponseUri.ToString();
                        Encoding encode = Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
                        if (stream != null)
                        {
                            StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(stream, encode);
                            string accessToken = streamReader.ReadToEnd().Replace("access_token=", "");
                            streamReader.Close();
                            response.Close();
                            return accessToken;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }
```

however I am constantly receiving this ambiguous error message

```
{
"error": {
"message": "Error validating verification code.",
"type": "OAuthException",
"code": 100
}
}
```

I checked the code 100 "Invalid parameter" doesn't means much to me at all.

anyone have had similar problem?

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240626/facebook-oauth-error-validating-verification-code-sometimes-happen

Comment: @Thomas, unfortunately not same problem

Answer (score 4):

1. Check you are adding correct code in the url
   For example

   ```
   http://www.xyz.com/?code=AQC399oXame3UKmoAMYnqkZOEXPDNa8ZUFEY9sc6I4YNQnNT-ZgHzpMNnQVZrCUBZVqJRIB1QrXC5xW58_8MNIgQol_PaQvYssUM8OiKjSY5aoqGLBMuCeeHsSqP_mRTd1xiK0iretZcXwMm_27lFYrWFw345Mxod_lfJuB8zI13E8wJUQiArXW_ZlGLNcyxh20#_=_
   ```

Code must be

```
    code = AQC399oXame3UKmoAMYnqkZOEXPDNa8ZUFEY9sc6I4YNQnNT-ZgHzpMNnQVZrCUBZVqJRIB1QrXC5xW58_8MNIgQol_PaQvYssUM8OiKjSY5aoqGLBMuCeeHsSqP_mRTd1xiK0iretZcXwMm_27lFYrWFw345Mxod_lfJuB8zI13E8wJUQiArXW_ZlGLNcyxh20
```

code should not include following in the end

```
    #_=_
```

If above did not solve the problem

2. redirect_uri must end with /

```
redirect_uri=http://www.xyz.com/
```

The following gives some times above mentioned error

```
redirect_uri=http://www.xyz.com
```

3. A lso make sure
 **App on Facebook** and **Website with Facebook Login** are set with same addresss
e.g http://www.xyz.com/

Comment: Wow, I had the same issue (no trailing slash). Hard to believe that you get an error response 400 Bad Request when that is omitted.

Comment: The absence of a trailing slash did *not* effect me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to send the user to the Facebook Login page to get a valid `code`. The code should then be used to get the `access_token` for the user.

Follow the [Authentication Guide](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/).

Comment: I did that in earlier code already. the 'code' part is working. as I said the 400 bad request happens when I requesting for authentication token

Comment: The error says there is something wrong with the code, so make sure it isn't being modified or altered in anyway. It might be the cause of the problem.

Comment: +1 to recover from the downvote. Even though this did not solve the problem, it still doesn't deserve a downvote. It may help others.

Answer (score 1):

I also got error message 400, when my app id and secret were wrong (i had messed up develop and production id-s and secrets).

Fixing them (watch also out for the correct host) fixed *this* problem for me.