# how to authorize a user on behalf of facebook app using facebook csharp sdk

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook

Getting error while authorising an user ....[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Atq0S.png)

this is my code .

public partial class facebook : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Request["code"] != null && Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                checkauthorization();
            }
        }

```
    protected void btnpost_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkauthorization();
    }

    public void checkauthorization()
    {
        string app_id = "appid";
        string app_secret = "app secret";
        string scope = "publish_stream,manage_pages";

        if (Request["code"] == null)
        {
            Response.Redirect(string.Format("http://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&scope={2}", app_id, Request.Url.AbsoluteUri, scope));

        }
        else
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> tokens = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            string url = string.Format("http://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&scope={2}&code={3}&client_secret={4}", app_id, Request.Url.AbsoluteUri, scope, Request["code"].ToString(), app_secret);
            HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
            using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
                string vals = reader.ReadToEnd();
                foreach (string token in vals.Split('&'))
                {
                    tokens.Add(token.Substring(0, token.IndexOf("=")),
                        token.Substring(token.IndexOf("=") + 1,
                        token.Length - token.IndexOf("=") - 1));
                }
            }
            string access_token = tokens["access_token"];
            var client = new FacebookClient(access_token);
            client.Post("/me/feed/", new { message = txtmsg.Text.Trim() });
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: do you have check this out ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10799235/facebook-access-token-400-bad-request

Comment: Eventhough, still i am geeting exception near httpwebresponse

Comment: You’re using a wrong (or outdated) endpoint. The login dialog base address is `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth`, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow

Comment: thank you,but for my website that functionality not require ,just i want to authorize the users on behalf of by facebook app and get access token for each user who has authorized..  to chieve this i am using facebook csharp sdk library.

Comment: can any one  please support me  to crack the issue what i am facing since a week